# Messaging App: Textview not autoresizing it's height to display full message

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, textview, messaging

For the ChatLogController of my messaging feature, I'm having trouble getting the message bubble to automatically adjust its size based on its textView content size. It's showing only one line from the textview as the rest of the text is truncated. Here's how I've defined my textView and the message bubbleContainer:

```
private let textView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.backgroundColor = .clear
    tv.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    tv.isScrollEnabled = false
    tv.isEditable = false
    tv.textColor = .white
    return tv
}()

private let bubbleContainer: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
    return view
}()
```

And here are the constraints:

```
addSubview(bubbleContainer)
    bubbleContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    bubbleContainer.anchor(top: topAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor)
    bubbleContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 250).isActive = true

    bubbleLeftAnchor = bubbleContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 12)
    bubbleLeftAnchor.isActive = false

    bubbleRightAnchor = bubbleContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -12)
    bubbleRightAnchor.isActive = false

    bubbleContainer.addSubview(textView)
    textView.anchor(top: bubbleContainer.topAnchor, left: bubbleContainer.leftAnchor,
                    bottom: bubbleContainer.bottomAnchor, right: bubbleContainer.rightAnchor,
                    paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 12)
```

The ChatLogController is a UICollectionViewController, and this is the way I've set up sizeForItemAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
    let estimatedSizeCell = MessageCell(frame: frame)
    estimatedSizeCell.message = messages[indexPath.row]
    estimatedSizeCell.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)
    let estimatedSize = estimatedSizeCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)
    
    return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedSize.height)
}
```

The delegate is set to self but it seems as if the function is not even being called.
in the pic below, you can see how the messages are being truncated and the cell height is stuck to 50 pixels, where it should have been adjusted to display the rest of the message:

[image]

Comment: why are you using textview, use label with number of lines 0 it will work

Comment: @GopiDonga so I just tried using label and now nothing is showing. Can you share an answer with how you were structure the label?

Comment: cell with label inside which has leading constraint grater than 90 and 0 from all other sides

Answer (score 0):

Inside cell take label with 0 number of lines which has following constraints:

- Leading: Grater than 90 superview
- All other with as usual